# Updating and rebuilding libGDX for iOS after changing IosGraphics.java

Tags: libgdx

In my game when I touch on advertisements and then press the back button to return to my game i am getting a black screen.  I referred this forum discussion http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=7673 which suggests a work-around in the libGDX library.

I tried to change `IosGraphics.java` but the change is not being reflected in the monotouch project.

I did the following :

1. extracted nightly.zip and opened `gdx-backend-iosmonotouch-sources`
2. From there I changed `IosGraphics.java`.
3. I then made a new jar file `gdx-backend-iosmonotouch.jar` and replaced it with original jar file in the nightly folder.
4. Compressed all the files from nightly folder in a new .zip file.
5. I used my new .zip file to make a new project through `gdx-setup-ui.jar`.
6. I tried to open my project in monotouch and from com-gdx-backendios.dll i found that the changes in `IosGraphics` are not being reflected.

Am i missing something? Or is there any other better way to do it?

I even tried to open `gdx-backend-iosmonotouch-sources.jar` with winrar and edit `IosGraphics.java` and save it.  This didn`t work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The libGDX build process may have some funky steps in it that you didn't do, so its probably safest to do the build the official way.  I don't know specifically what is different than what you did ...

One note, the `gdx-backend-iosmonotouch-sources.jar` is provided to make it possible to look up and read libGDX code from your editor while building your own project.  It isn't packaged for rebuilding the libGDX code.

Here are the official steps for rebuilding libGDX:

1. Download the source tree from [github](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx) (either with git or you can fetch a `.zip` of the source tree).
2. (Install `ant` if you haven't got it already.)
3. Fetch the lateset binaries to go with the sources: `ant -f fetch.xml`
4. Make your change to `./backends/gdx-backend-iosmonotouch/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/ios/IOSGraphics.java`
5. Build a new distribution .zip: `ant`
6. Install the generated .zip via `gdx-setup-ui.jar`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I followed the above steps but still changes are not reflected. I checked the methods in IOSgraphics.dll from monotouch through assembly browser . here is .zip that i got after changes                                               https://dl.dropbox.com/u/105613097/libgdx-0.9.9-SNAPSHOT.zip  I again unzip this file and used its gdx-setup-ui.jar to make new project. Am I missing something in this???